# What do you call a person who doesn't pay attention to the principles of ergonomics?

Tags: phrase-requests

How do you say that a person does not pay attention to ergonomics (like at a computer) in a concise way?  Options I've come up with include:

- He does not use ergonomics.
- He does not follow ergonomics.
- He is not ergonomic.

Any better ideas?

Comment: He is not ergonomically-correct.

Comment: Ergonomics is actually a pretty specific field of science. I would assume someone who "follows ergonomics" keeps abreast with the important journal articles and that someone who "is ergonomic" has, perhaps, a very comfortable lap. I'd say JeffSahol's answer - "he is ignorant of ergonomics" is correct.

Comment: Is there something special about ergonomics here? This how question could be worded replacing 'ergonomics' with 'X'..

Comment: "The laminectomy in operating room 3"?

Comment: That is, are you looking for a generic grammatical negatives like 'non-X' or 'not Xic' or are you looking for an antonym specifically of ergonomic, like maybe clusy or inefficient or energy-wasteful or etc?

Comment: I'm actually trying to use it in a poem of sorts, and ideally the sentence needs to go "He never _____ ergonomics."  The first two words need to stay the same, ergonomics could move around.

Comment: In a word, I would call him uncomfortable. But that doesn't fit your poem.

Answer (score 10):

> He is ignorant of ergonomics.

or, if he's aware of the issue but chooses to ignore it:

> He ignores ergonomics.

Comment: Gotta love the divergence of the definitions of ignore-ant due to both (willfully ignoring) and (being uneducated about) word structure.

Answer (score 2):

> He is not [ergonomically-minded](http://mattresskingmt.com/adjustable-beds-good-sleeping/).

Or

> He is not the *ergonomic type*.

Comment: "He is ergonomically illiterate". "He is ergonomics-challenged". "He is ergonomically compromised". "He is ergonomics-resistant". "He is an ergonomic refusenik". "He is anti-ergonomic". "He is ergonomically rebellious". "He is an ergonomic insurgent". "He lacks the ergonomic urge". "He is an ergnoramus".

Answer (score 0):

Erganidiot? Erganomitard? Hump-backed?

Answer (score 0):

One who has mastered and can and does apply the principles of physics is a physicist; one who does not meet these criteria is a non-physicist. By analogy, I would suggest that the word you seek is  *non-ergonomicist.*

Answer (score -1):

slacko,  slacker, slack-arse(variants), dolt.

Comment: What have any of those suggestions got to do with the question?